# (discord.py + wavelink) AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encoded'

Tags: python, discord.py, attributeerror

I don't know how, but the issue just fixed itself today.

Original post:
I am trying to get a Discord music bot from [here](https://github.com/zz-xx/discord-music-bot) to work. I already fixed a bunch of errors, but right now I am stuck with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "(bot folder)\cogs\audio\play.py", line 111, in play
    await vc.play(track)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\wavelink\player.py", line 590, in play
    'encodedTrack': track.encoded(),
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encoded'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encoded'
```

I looked into wavelink's player.py file and found the line which (probably) causes the issue:

```
        data = {
           >>> 'encodedTrack': track.encoded, <<<
            'position': start or 0,
            'volume': volume or self._volume
        }
```

From my perspective it looks like `track` is a list, but there is no attribute `list.encoded` in python, so the command fails. How do I fix this issue?

What I did:

- launched `(bot folder)/bot.py`
- typed `/play cool tunes` in my server
- waited for my music to start playing

What I expected:
m u s i c

What actually happened:
Discord threw an interaction error at me and the console showed the error

Comment: It seems like your `track` variable being passed into `await vc.play(track)` must be a list instead of whatever else it is expecting. Check what’s in this variable, because it probably isn’t what you want.

Comment: i honestly don't know how, but today it just fixed itself. thanks for the comment tho!

Comment: That's good to here. If you ever want to see what's in a variable, often just using something like `print(track)` will show you the contents of the track variable, which in this case would presumably be a list. It's always my go-to strategy when trying to figure out errors like this. Hope that helps!